# How can I add custom angular material mat-error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of items and now I am adding data from input box to that list.
I would like to show mat-error for duplicate entry under that input box.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="validation()" [(ngModel)]="package">
    <mat-error>Duplicate Entry</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Suggest me a proper way to tackle such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use template driven forms. I think you want like this

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="validation()" [(ngModel)]="package" name="package" #package="ngModel">
  <mat-error *ngIf="package.invalid">Duplicate Entry</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Add you required error message in mat-error

check this link https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use ***ngIf to hide or show the error**. Take a variable, and make it true, if a duplicate is found.

example: `<mat-error *ngIf="duplicateFound">Duplicate Entry</mat-error>`

2. **when the user enters the new item, you need to check from the current list of items**, if it is already present, then set the `duplicateFound` to true

**your template**

```
<input matInput (keyup.enter)="validation()" [(ngModel)]="package">
```

**your component**

```js
duplicateFound: boolean = false;
items = [];

validation() {
  items.forEach(item => {
    if (item === this.package) {
      this.duplicateFound = true; // now your error will be displayed in browser
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: keep this in your template `{{ duplicateFound }}`. and check if the value is changing or not from false to true, on clicking the button.